# Plesk + Apache + PHP (FastCGI): Constant session permissions problems, conflicts between HTTP / HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ssl, session

I've just moved a collection of sites over to a brand-new server, running Apache 2.2.3, PHP 5.3, and Plesk 10.1.1. I am having problems with file permissions on PHP sessions, which are being stored in `/var/lib/php/session`.

I originally set the permissions like so for this folder:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 apache psacln 8192 Mar 22 23:25 session
```

This worked fine, for **HTTP** sessions. Files were being saved in that folder with these permissions:

```
-rw------- 1 client1        psacln 0 Mar 22 23:24 sess_507...
-rw------- 1 client2        psacln 0 Mar 22 23:25 sess_8o1...
```

The problem, however, is that PHP scripts accessed via HTTPS do not seem to be run by the same `client1` or `client2` user. I deleted files in the session directory and accessed a login page via HTTPS to see how sessions were being saved when initiated via this protocol:

```
-rw------- 1 apache         apache 0 Mar 22 23:25 sess_507...
```

So, for whatever reason, sessions initiated by clients browsing with HTTPS were being saved by `apache:apache`, while sessions from HTTP clients were saved with `someclient:psacln`.

What  I'd like to ask:

1. How can I avoid this problem with session permissions? When sessions are created via unencrypted HTTP and a client visits an HTTPS portion of the site, permission errors are shown, since `apache:apache` tries to access the session save created by `someclient:psacln`. The converse is also true.

   1. Can I change the user which runs the Apache HTTPS server, via Plesk or the command line?
   2. If not, can I have PHP sessions save with `rw-rw----` permissions, and then add `apache` to the `psacln` group?
   3. Any other suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `/etc/php.ini` file:

```
session.save_path = "0;0660;/var/lib/php/session"
```

PHP 5.3.5 mabe will save your session file as `-rw-r--` if it does, then you need to edit your application, use the code instead only `start_session()`:

```
usermod(0);
start_session();
```

then it will save the session files with `-rw-rw--` permission.

You will also need to change your apache group to psacln (your server maybe running as apache:apache because some updated from apache has overwrite the config file).

Edit your `httpd.conf`

change from:

```
user = apache
group = apache
```

To:

```
user = apache
group = psacln
```

Now if you change from mod_php to FastCGI and back, you will not have conflict with your session permissions.

Don't forget to restart your apache server after the changes `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

If you are using a debian distro, your daemon command will be `/etc/init.d/apache restart` and your config files will be inside a synonymous folder like `/etc/php/apache/php.ini` and `/etc/apache/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache/apache.conf`